# Count of matching column with aggregation on another column

Tags: sql, count, case, aggregation

Assuming I have the following data:

```
 ---- ------ ----------
| id | text | timetamp |
 ---- ------ ----------
|  1 | X    |      100 |
 ---- ------ ----------
|  2 | X    |      100 |
 ---- ------ ----------
|  3 | X    |      101 |
 ---- ------ ----------
|  4 | Y    |      100 |
 ---- ------ ----------
|  5 | Y    |      101 |
 ---- ------ ----------
```

and I want to find the total appearances of either X or Y within table.text, but count only one per timestamp, i.e., the results should look like this:

```
 --------- ---------
| X_count | Y_count |
 --------- ---------
|       2 |       2 |
 --------- ---------
```

because rows 1+2 happened in the same second.

The best thing I came up with was this:

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(IF(T.total_X_count > 0, 1, 0)) AS X_count,
    SUM(IF(T.total_Y_count > 0, 1, 0)) AS Y_count
    FROM
    (SELECT id,
        MAX(CASE WHEN table.text like "%X%" THEN 1 END) AS "total_X_count", 
        MAX(CASE WHEN table.text like "%Y%" THEN 1 END) AS "total_Y_count"
    FROM table
    GROUP BY(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(table.datetime)))
    ) AS T
;
```

I'd like to know if it is possible to do it more efficiently.

Comment: But the question was badly phrased - right now it is **ambiguous**. I can't accept the answer as it answers a meaning other than the one I intended.

Comment: asked it again :\
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72184462/count-of-a-matching-column-with-aggregation-on-another-column

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Text, count(distinct timeTamp) as cnt
from myTable
group by Text
```

would give you the result as:

```
X, 2
Y, 2
```

If you need to make this as:

```
X, Y
2, 2
```

Then check cross tab. It might have built-in or extension function for the backend you are using already (ie: for postgreSQL there is tablefunc() and for MS SQL server pivot).

Comment: I want to group it by `LIKE` text match and not exact text match (edited the data in the question for more clarity)