# Count of a matching column with aggregation on another column

Tags: sql, count, case, aggregation

Assuming I have the following data:

```
 ---- ------ ------------
| id | text | timetamp   |
 ---- ------ ------------
|  1 | X1   |      100.7 |
 ---- ------ ------------
|  2 | X2   |      100.2 |
 ---- ------ ------------
|  3 | 3X   |      101.0 |
 ---- ------ ------------
|  4 | Y1   |      100.2 |
 ---- ------ ------------
|  5 | 2Y   |      101.3 |
 ---- ------ ------------
```

and I want to find the total appearances `WHERE table.text LIKE %Y%` and `WHERE table.text LIKE %X%`, but count only one per timestamp, i.e., the results should look like this:

```
 --------- ---------
| X_count | Y_count |
 --------- ---------
|       2 |       2 |
 --------- ---------
```

because rows 1+2 happened in the same second.

The best thing I came up with was this:

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(IF(T.total_X_count > 0, 1, 0)) AS X_count,
    SUM(IF(T.total_Y_count > 0, 1, 0)) AS Y_count
    FROM
    (SELECT id,
        MAX(CASE WHEN table.text like "%X%" THEN 1 END) AS "total_X_count", 
        MAX(CASE WHEN table.text like "%Y%" THEN 1 END) AS "total_Y_count"
    FROM table
    GROUP BY(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(table.datetime)))
    ) AS T
;
```

I'd like to know if it is possible to do it more efficiently.

Comment: Note: this is NOT the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72170471/count-of-matching-column-with-aggregation-on-another-column
I wanted to edit the other one but I was scolded.

Comment: How come the result is 2, 2?

Comment: X-s: Rows 1, 2 happened in the same second, so I count them as one; row 3 happened in another second so I count it as 1; 1 + 1 = 2.


Y-s:  row 4, 5 happened in different seconds, so I count each of them as 1, 1+1=2